# PCB Design guidelines for "hot swapping"

Tags: pcb-design, circuit-protection, esd

I am designing a PCB with JST EH connectors, which are connected to a multi pin socket exposed to the user. The multi pin socket provides +24V, CAN H, CAN L and GND. I have experienced that the PCB does not like to "hot swap" the connector exposed to the user, and sometimes fail/dies.

It is no problem as long as I disconnect power to the PCB before connecting/disconnecting the connector.

Would like some input/guidance on the PCB design to be able to "hot swap" these connectors. The connectors and socket pins are all equal in length, so GND will not be connected first.

**EDIT:**
The connector brand is CNLinko. Example product: LP-12-5 pin. All pins are equal in length, so GND is not connected first unfortunately. Is there any way to protect the circuit properly when using such a connector?

24VDC input schematic:
[image]

Comment: well, pick different connectors, I guess, would be the design guidance one would expected to get. I bet you've ruled that out due to external factors – but we don't know these, so all our recommendations are likely to just run afoul of them. Please tell us what makes you stick to these connectors if you want hot-plugging! They really seem to be an odd choice to me.

Comment: In what way does the board "fail/die"?  My guess is that that is important information.  Dead component part numbers / failure mechanism / partial schematic - *anything* - ?

Comment: Do you have the typical low-capacitance TVS array protection on the CAN bus lines?

Comment: @SpehroPefhany no but I just read up on that, so will add them for next revision.

Comment: @winny I think you mean first-make/last-break; MBB is something else.

Comment: @AnalogKid there has been multiple things happening, but thin film fuses have blown, the MCU has blown. Will add 24V input schematic in post.

Comment: @Hearth You are indeed correct. Too late to edit now, but I'll remember it for next time.

Comment: You simply must have first-make/last-break on the GND lines. Change the connector or if card edge, make the GND fingers longer than the others.

Comment: @eidetech Multiple different problems happening seemingly at random is potentially indicative of ESD issues. I would recommend double checking your ESD protection; add TVS diodes if you don't have them. And as winny says, a connector that offers first-make/last-break is absolutely essential.

Comment: @Hearth Yes, will add TVS diodes. Will check if manufacturer has option for connector with longer GND pin. Thanks for input

Comment: @eidetech I believe JST's EH series does not have first-make/last-break options. You probably want to use a different connector. There may be options that would work in the same footprint; 2.5 mm is a very common pitch (and you can probably fit 0.1" = 2.54 mm connectors too).

Comment: @Hearth JST EH is not exposed to the customer; that one is permanently connected. The connector exposed to the customer is the CNLinko LP-12 style connector.

Comment: @eidetech I am having trouble getting any information on this CNLinko LP-12, so I can't make any recommendations.

Comment: Is the board connected to anything else?

Comment: A relay fed from the 24 V, that connects the two CAN bus lines with a little delay, would help during plug in, but does not solve the (minor) problems during pull out.

Comment: First, define what "sometimes fail/dies" means. Is it internal supply collapse (brownout), or reversal? Is it overvoltage on the connected module, or anywhere along the connected path? Is it pulling up the CAN bus to 24V (module initially unpowered, consider GND, +24V, 3.3V/5V supplies initially shorted together; thus CAN port sees ~ -24V transiently) and breaking things? Etc. Some of these can be determined by inspection (please provide schematics of your system), others require measurement (oscilloscope waveforms).

Comment: First, start with TVS diodes on every pin. Then a Shottky diode from GND to 24V and a >10uF capacitor.

Answer (score 1):

> Is there any way to protect the circuit properly when using such a
> connector?

The easiest way is for ground to connect first with a connector.

Edit:

If this isn't a good way you can add a pmos fet to 'block' the voltage to your load safely on connects or disconnects.

Using a high side switch is the only good way I know of to limit startup current and keep current from flowing into the unit. You can use a circuit below or 'roll your own' without a hotswap controller (ie by using just a pull down resistor.)

[image]
https://www.nexperia.com/applications/industrial-and-power/hot-swap-comms-infrastructure.html